# Best way to change radio button when the post processing takes 5-10 seconds

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a two radio buttons. I have onclick events on them. Whenever there is an onclick, I do some processing. This processing takes some time.

Since there is an onclick event on both the radio buttons, until the processing is done, the radio button don't change visually.

Ex: If I want to change from radio button A to B, it will only change if the processing is done.

How can I do the post processing such that, visually the radio buttons are changed and the javascript function which does the post processing runs in the background.

Comment: I was going through some posts. Seems like **setTimeOut** can be used.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: setTimeout doesn't seem to work with chrome and firefox. it works with IE.

In chrome and firefox it still waits for the function to complete the processing.

Comment: be careful to using setTimeOut as your process could end early or later when the value you set on setTimeOut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your process is asynchronous, consider using `dojo/Deferred`.

`dojo/Deferred` will return a promise that gets resolved when the asynchronous thread is complete.

Solution using `setTimeOut` will force you to specify a duration for your process, as you process could resolve sooner or later, hardcoding a value in `setTimeOut` it is not a good option has you risk to make wait your user a longer time that necessary or you risk to run your code before the actual process hs been completed.

More information here:

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/Deferred.html#dojo-deferred

Comment: This worked. Deferred with setTimeout was consistent

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dojo/aspect](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/aspect.html) and just use [aspect.after](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/aspect.html#after) the click event to do any of your processing

Comment: The above didn't work. It was not working in Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Use dojo's Publish/Subscribe model, You can visually change the radio buttons  and in the very next line publish to a channel from onClick handler that do post processing.
 [Dojo's Pub/Sub documentation.](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/quickstart/topics.html)